# Secure Logstash and Filebeats communication

Tags: ssl, logstash, filebeat, elk

We are working on an integration where we need to take logs from Filebeat through Logstash. However, Filebeat and Logstash are hosted in different networks. In order to secure the communication, we want to implement SSL. My question, is self-signed CA certificate sufficient to secure the communication? or is it mandatory to deploy a third-party CA certificate?

We need suggestion for this.